# Case-Insensitive search not working

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Consider this is my mapping and settings

```
$arr = [
        'index' => 'test1',
        'body' => [
            'settings' => [
               'analysis' => [
                    'analyzer' => [
                            'name_analyzer' => [
                            'type' => 'custom',
                            'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                            'filter' => [
                              'lowercase',
                              'asciifolding',
                              'word_delimiter'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            "mappings" => [
                "info" => [
                    "properties" => [
                        "Name" => [
                            "type" => "string",
                            "index" => "analyzed",
                            "analyzer" => "name_analyzer"
                        ],
                        "Address" => [
                            "type" => "string",
                            "index" => "analyzed",
                            "analyzer" => "name_analyzer"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

after index two Name & Address as

1. abc some_address1
2. Abc some_address2

when I search for name 'A' I don't get any document in result.
but when I search for name 'a' i get both the documents in the result

so my question is even though I have set analyser why my search is not case-insensitive?

My Search Query

```
$query['index'] = 'test1';
    $query['type']  = 'info';
    $query['body'] = [
        'query'=> [
            'bool' => [
                'should' => [
                    [
                        'prefix' => [
                            'Name' => 'a'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Comment: Please show your actual code

Comment: It would be helpful if you post your query. Some queries, like term query, don't go through the analyzer at query time, thus you won't get any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html), as the doc says, the prefix is not analyzed at query time. Meaning that if you put `A` as prefix it won't match anything because `Name` field is being lowercased.

So, I would suggest that you manually lowercase the prefix if you want to continue using prefix query.

If that is not an option you can use a [query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) with a wildcard as follows:

```
$query['index'] = 'test1';
    $query['type']  = 'info';
    $query['body'] = [
        'query'=> [
            'bool' => [
                'should' => [
                    [
                        'query_string' => [
                            'default_field' => 'Name',
                            'query' => 'A*',
                            'analyze_wildcard' => 'true'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Comment: surely this query gives me name=abc in result but i need 'Abc' also in result. how to go for that?

Comment: prefix query with `a` as prefix will give you both `name=abc` and `name=Abc`. And query string with either `A*` or `a*` will give you both as well

Comment: I am using the same query suggested by you, and this is my output result `{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test1",
        "_type": "info",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "Name": "abc",
          "Address": "CHembur Mum. 81"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}` I am not getting name='Abc' in result. Why its not working buddy?

Comment: Just created your index with two documents name=abc and name=Abc and everything seems to work: https://www.dropbox.com/s/whztgn6qs3fzeqk/Screenshot%202015-07-28%2013.10.36.png?dl=0

Comment: sorry my fault, for testing purpose i recreated the mapping with name as not_analyzed. sorry. It worked